# I have a list of numbers where the 1st digit is appended to a new list, then last, then 2nd, then 2nd last and so on

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following is my code:

```
def alt_ele():
    mylist=list(input("Enter the elements: "))
    newlist=[int(i) for i in mylist]
    final_list=[]
    try:
        for x in range(len(newlist)):
            final_list.append(newlist.pop(0))
            final_list.append(newlist.pop())
            print(final_list)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Now the Input I am giving is:

I/N: Enter the elements: 12345
My desired output is `[1,5,2,4,3]`
But the output I am actually getting is:

```
[1,5]
[1,5,2,4]
```

Can anyone please help me figure out where am I going wrong? I tried but, I cannot figure it out by myself
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a longer example: `'123456789' -> [1,9,2,8,3,7,5,6]`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Sebastian yes, assuming you forgot the 4 :)

Answer (score 2):

The `print` statement needs to be after the `try`/`except` clause:

```
def alt_ele():
    mylist=list(input("Enter the elements: "))
    newlist=[int(i) for i in mylist]
    final_list=[]
    try:
        for x in range(len(newlist)):
            final_list.append(newlist.pop(0))
            final_list.append(newlist.pop())
    except IndexError:
        pass
    print(final_list)
```

With this, we get the desired output.

I don't think this is the best solution, so here's one way of avoiding the `try`/`except` clause:

```
def alt_ele():
    mylist=list(input("Enter the elements: "))
    newlist=[int(i) for i in mylist]
    final_list=[]
    switch = False
    while newlist:
        final_list.append(newlist.pop(-switch))
        switch = not switch
    print(final_list)
```

Comment: You really only need `try` around the `pop` statements.

Comment: True, but I tried to have minimal editing to his own function. I wouldn't use a `for` loop here either, but instead a `while newlist`, as the `for` loop will never come close to completing.

Comment: can you please tell me what does "-switch" does here exactly? because If we directly give just newlist.pop(switch) it does the job

Comment: `switch` is a Boolean value which essentially changes whether we are popping from the start or end of the list. If `switch=False`, `newlist.pop(-switch) == newlist.pop(0)`, so we pop from the start. If `switch=True`, `newlist.pop(-switch) == newlist.pop(-1)`, so we pop from the end. Note that `-True == -1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently printing the list in every iteration of the loop. Be careful with the indentation.

It should be:

```
for x in range(len(newlist)):
    final_list.append(newlist.pop(0))
    final_list.append(newlist.pop())
print(final_list)
```